# Reverse Printing in LinkedList C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, reverse

I know this question is asked but my problem is different than just reverse printing.

```
void printReverse(ListNode* p){
   if(!p)
       return;
   printReverse(p->next);
   cout << (p->val) << "->";
   return;
}
```

Given Output is

```
3->2->1->3->2->3->
```

What I want is

```
3->2->1->
3->2->
3->
```

It is a single linked list and I'm confused about where to put

```
cout<< endl;
```

I cannot declare "#include string" or any other header to this file.

if I do like this

```
void printReverse(ListNode* p){
   if(!p)
       return;
   printReverse(p->next);
   cout << (p->val) << "->";
   cout << endl;  //LOOK AT HERE, DIFFERENCE IS HERE
   return;
}
```

Then my output is like this:

```
3->
2->
1->
3->
2->
3->
```

EDIT: For someone who wants to see another outputs:
MyOutput:

```
5->6->7->8->9->5->6->7->8->5->6->7->5->6->5->
```

What I want:

```
5->6->7->8->9->
5->6->7->8->
5->6->7->
5->6->
5->
```

This is the main file:

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    ListNode a(1);
    ListNode b(2);
    ListNode c(3);
    a.next = &b;
    b.next = &c;

    ListNode* d = new ListNode(9);
    ListNode* e = new ListNode(8);
    ListNode* f = new ListNode(7);
    ListNode* g = new ListNode(6);
    ListNode* h = new ListNode(5);

    d->next = e;
    e->next = f;
    f->next = g;
    g->next = h;
    // The Program continues to another functions
    // ....
    // In somewhere here the program calls reverseprint function

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2: I cannot declare to my "reverseprint.ccp" file any other header. It is the rule.
EDIT3: The first expected output:

```
3->2->1->
3->2->
3->
```

is for:

```
printReverse(a);
printReverse(b);
printReverse(c);
// I believe it is like that.
```

Comment: Indeed, this might be tricky to figure out if you were staring at the code written on a piece of paper. But you've got a computer in front of you, so fire up a debugger and *see* where the code needs to go!

Comment: `cout << "\n"` just before the last `return;`?

Comment: as I edited, If I cout << "\n" just before the last return; it do like above. Do I miss something or should I do something different?

Comment: is it right that you have a single list containing `[3,2,3,1,2,3]` ? If so, where are the boundaries supposed to be, can you give more examples? Or are you doing something lke  `for (auto& node : list) print_reverse(node);`

Comment: What is your rule for producing the output you want? What is the input?

Comment: The integers (node data) -the last included- are followed by"->" characters. The output ends with "endl". It is recommended to implement this function recursively. You can use helper functions. If the given head pointer is NULL, just print an empty line.

Comment: I'm a little uncerrtain how this works at all. Surely you sould just be printing 3->2->1. Or are you printing a then b then c?

Comment: @luckykaa first a, then b then c. My fault , I didn't write those.

Comment: so you need the endl where the function returns for the last time... Just before the first return statement.

Comment: @luckykaa correct. However how can I know the first return statement?

Comment: Actually I think I was looking at it backwards... The easiest way would be to wrap the function in another function.

Answer (score 3):

You should to use "std::List" and a reverse iterator like that

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main ()
{
  std::list<int> mylist;
  for (int i=1; i<=5; ++i) mylist.push_back(i);

  std::cout << "mylist backwards:";
  for (std::list<int>::reverse_iterator rit=mylist.rbegin(); rit!=mylist.rend(); ++rit)
    std::cout << ' ' << *rit;

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

And you will have this output :

```
mylist backwards: 5 4 3 2 1
```